# How can you add data into a set column taken from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, innodb

I'm actually building a database on phpMyAdmin and I'm asking my self if something is possible and how could I implement it?

The fact is that I'm building lists through a website and then saving it inside of my database, but this list is only composed of items I already have stored in my database on another table.

I thought than a column with a `SET` datatype and all the selected items would be a memory gain and a clarity improvement instead of creating **x** lines linked to the created list by an ID column.

So, the question I'm asking is, can I create this kind of set for a column, which will update by it-self when I'll add items in the other table ? If yes, can I do it through phpMyAdmin interface or do I have to work on the MySQL server itself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Right now your question is not clear to me. Can you provide a simple example of what you want to achieve? Give tables and example data and this "set" functionality. Do you mean mysql sets (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html)?

Comment: If your question is about which database structure strategy is best (SET in single column vs linked table), it's not really possible to answer either way without knowing whether you need to query/search the values stored, or whether they will only ever really be used for just reading out.

Comment: Hi guys, you're right, I'm lacking precision on the trouble I'm facing.
The fact is that I'm building a dictionary and I have a first table which lists all the words with unique IDs and the table I'm asking for is the one that will store what each dictionary is composed of. The fact is that I'll have to build tons of dictionaries and if I could store each of them in a column, that has a 'set' datatype I guess that I'll be gaining tons of memory. 
Thanks for your answers and I'm sorry for the lack of explanation on my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it won't be possible to use the **SET** datatype in my application because it can only store up to 64 items and I'll be manipulating around a thousand.

I'm still interested if any of you guys have an idea on how to do it because a table with **x** times(ID,wordID#) (see my situation, explained a bit higher in this post, on the answers part) doesn't seem really optimized and a light-weighted option.

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to simulate a `SET` in a `BLOB` (max 64K bits) or `MEDIUMBLOB` (max 16M bits), but it takes a bit of code -- find the byte, modify it using `&` or `|`, stuff it back in.

Before MySQL 8.0 bitwise operations (eg ANDing two SETs, etc) was limited to 64 bits.  With 8.0, `BLOBs` can be operated on that way.

If your `SETs` tend to be sparse, then a list of bit numbers (in a commalist or in a table) may be more compact.  However, "dictionary" implies to me that your `SETs` are likely to be somewhat dense.

If you are doing some other types of operations, clue us in.